# http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ does not show login screen

Tags: apache-2.2, installation

I installed phpmyadmin and apache 2.2 on my system.
I have configured my conf/httpd file as said by changing the  "DirectoryIndex index.php"

But when i try to access my localhost/phpmyadmin/, a php code page appears and not the login page.

Help appreciated.

Thanks,
Shiva..

Comment: More information? What have you done to try and solve your problem. What do you mean by code page. What do your logs say.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install php so it can render the code.

Depends on your OS which is not mentioned, 
just google on how to install php (ex, in centos: **yum install php** or **apt-get install php5** for debian alike ; it should also install the dependencies)

Then you need to restart apache and it should execute the php code.

Good luck

Comment: The OP should also use his distro's package system to install phpmyadmin.  It will certainly depend on php and probably libapache2-mod-php5 etc., so they'll automatically get installed too.